# How do I Keep What is in the ComboBox After Hitting Enter

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-events

I have a combobox set up with type ahead on it. So when a user starts typing a name the rest of it gets filled in automatically. I also have a listener set up for the keyboard so that when the user presses the enter key, it performs a search for the user they are looking for.

I have a button for the search action and when they type in a name and click on the button with the mouse everything works fine, but when they type in a name and then hit the enter key, the search gets performed, but the combobox gets cleared (or maybe gets a carriage return) right before the search action is performed so it comes up blank.

How do I keep the data in the combo box when they hit the enter key?

This is my code for the key press event:

```
Private Sub check_key(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)

   If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then
       MessageBox.Show(sender.text)
       perform_search_button.PerformClick()
   End If

End Sub
```

The messagebox always comes up empty.

I found my answer. I have to close the combobox manually for the value to be preserved. So I added this code and it works fine now:

```
If e.KeyCode <> Keys.Enter Then
    sender.DroppedDown = False
Else
    perform_search_button.PerformClick()
End If
```

This closes the main dropdown but still keeps the type ahead and auto fill box open.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Looks can be deceiving. It is real code. I copied from my working program.

Comment: Then you meant KeyDown event, not KeyPress event.  Probably need to document your ComboBox a bit more for us to see what is happening.